# How to configure Windows Server 2012 R2 to allow interactive services?

Tags: service, configuration, windows-services, interactive, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed a new interactive service.

I tried in Service manager to set property „Allow service to interact with desktop“.

After that I found in Event Viewer error message from Service Control Manager: “**The service is marked as an interactive service.  However, the system is configured to not allow interactive services.  This service may not function properly.**”

All my attempts to fix this error have failed:

- The Server has an interactive service allowed - 
  value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows\NoInteractiveServices  is 0
- Windows service Interactive Services Detection is running.
  (“net start ui0detect”)
- The system is rebooted.

Error message still remains.  What needs to be done to correct server configuration to allow interactive services?

System: Windows Server 2012 R2 Version 6.3 (Build 9600)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Did you ever find or use an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Product Line
Windows Server 2008/12

Environment
Windows Services

Cause
Windows Server no longer allows interactive services by default.

*Warning: This article contains information about editing the registry. Improper changes to the registry can permanently damage the operating system.
Always backup the registry before making any changes.*
Resolution
In order to get this service to run you will have to adjust a registry key by following steps below.

```
1. Open registry editor by going to start and typing in regedit.exe.
2. On the registry tree, navigate to HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows.
3. Find the DWORD "NoInteractiveServices".
4. Change the value from a 1 to 0. 
5. Restart the Server.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a service compiled with Embarcadero C++ Builder. Windows also complained about interactive services not being allowed until I restarted the server. This was the case for both Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012. On the 2008 instance was NoInteractiveServices was already turned off. But on Server 2012 NoInteractiveServices was on and allowed my service to run when the OS completed the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue.

1. Open `regedit` and go to key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows` and set `NoInteractiveServices` to 0.
2. Reboot the server.
3. Open an elevated `cmd` and type:

   ```
   sc config ui0detect start= auto

   sc start ui0detect
   ```

Now see if you're problem was solved. ;)